# Mover Scroll com Botões

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-eventos

Preciso mover um scroll horizontal com botões.
Tenho uma galeria horizontal com scroll horizontal, e preciso que ao clicar nos botões no canto superior direito *"próximo/anterior"* o ***scroll*** mova para a próxima imagem ou anterior dependendo do botão clicado.

Exemplo:
[image: Exemplo]

código:

```js
function mostra(theId){
 var theArray= new Array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6');
 for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
  if(theArray[i] == theId){
   document.getElementById(theId).style.display='block';
  }else{
   document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
  }
 }
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.menu_horizontal {
 position: relative;
 /*padding: 0 11px;*/
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.trilho_classe {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.trilho_classe_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.trilho_classe_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
 
.trilho_classe_Link2 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}
#caixas{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
 #caixas2{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 .caixa1{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
 .caixa2{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
```

```html
<div id="caixas">
 <div class="caixa1">
  <div class="menu_horizontal">
   <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">
    
    <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
     <a onclick="mostra('item1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="true">Galeria1</a>
     <a onclick="mostra('item2');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="false">Galeria2</a>
     <a onclick="mostra('item3');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="false">Galeria3</a>
    <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position_btcx">
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <div id="item1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas dragscroll">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas dragscroll">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas dragscroll">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Os botões referentes estão no canto superior direito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é um scroll para os lados movendo o scroll da div na mesma largura das imagens da galeria. Como a largura das imagens não tem nenhuma relação com a largura da janela (ou da div onde elas estão agrupadas), fica impossível (ou pelo menos muito complicado) fazer o scroll para mostrar exatamente a próxima que está fora da janela (que você chamou de "oculta").

Para realizar o efeito, criei algumas funções que movem o scroll para os lados de acordo com o botão clicado (veja explicações no código).

Se você notar na função `scrollSuave()`, possui um código de *easing* chamado `easeOutCubic`. Esse código é responsável pelo comportamento suave do scroll. Você pode trocar pelo que mais lhe agradar **[nesta página](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294)** com diversas funções já prontas, basta trocar o `return` da função.

Veja em funcionamento:

```js
function mostra(theId){
   var theArray= new Array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
   for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
      if(theArray[i] == theId){
         document.getElementById(theId).style.display='block';
      }else{
         document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
      }
   }
}

// Cria um evento "click" para cada botão
var botScroll = document.querySelectorAll(".position_btcx .button_cx");
for(var x=0; x<botScroll.length; x++){
   (function(x){
      botScroll[x].onclick = function(){
         moveScroll(x, cxAtiva().box_ativo, cxAtiva().img_width);
      }
   })(x);
}

// Função que faz o scroll suave
function scrollSuave(old, des, atu, ele){
    var easeOutCubic = function (t) { return (--t)*t*t+1 };
    atu += 1; // move de 1 em 1 pixel. Aumentando o valor, irá aumentar a velocidade
    var ease = easeOutCubic(atu/100);
    var del = des-old;
    del *= ease;
    del += old;
    ele.scrollTo(del, 0);
    if(atu < 100){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function (){
        scrollSuave(old, des, atu, ele);
      });
    }
}

// Função para buscar e retornar a galeria ativa
function cxAtiva(){
   var ele = document.querySelectorAll(".conteudocaixas");
   for(var x=0; x<ele.length; x++){
      if(ele[x].parentNode.style.display == "block") break;
   }

   return {
      box_ativo: x, // retorna a galeria visível (ativa)
      img_width: ele[x].querySelector("img").offsetWidth // retorna a largura das imagens
   }
}

function moveScroll(idx, cca, wid){
   var ele = document.querySelectorAll(".conteudocaixas");
   var ccs = ele[cca];
   var ccs_s = ccs.scrollLeft;
   // idx == 1 significa que segundo botão foi clicado (para a direita)
   scrollSuave(ccs_s, idx == 1 ? wid+ccs_s : ccs_s-wid, 0, ccs);
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.menu_horizontal {
 position: relative;
 /*padding: 0 11px;*/
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.trilho_classe {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.trilho_classe_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.trilho_classe_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
 
.trilho_classe_Link2 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}
#caixas{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
 #caixas2{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 .caixa1{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
 .caixa2{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
```

```html
<div id="caixas">
 <div class="caixa1">
  <div class="menu_horizontal">
   <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">
    
    <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
     <a onclick="mostra('item1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="true">Galeria1</a>
     <a onclick="mostra('item2');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="false">Galeria2</a>
     <a onclick="mostra('item3');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="false">Galeria3</a>
    <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position_btcx">
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <div id="item1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas dragscroll">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas dragscroll">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas dragscroll">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não existe maneira de pegar a posição de cada "imagem" e colocar para rolar o scroll certo pra próxima sem atribuir um valor fixo ao movimento?

Comment: Se vc conseguir ajustar as imagens para que apareçam certinho na largura da tela, seria possível. Mas dessa forma acho muito complicado.